# What is the PHPSpreadsheet character count or word count limit of a cell

Tags: phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Is it possible to increase the character limit of an Excel spreadsheet from within PHP?

Comment: what is your current limit and what are you trying to reach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any notes or settings [in the documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) about an existing character limit or even setting your own max cell character count.

[Microsoft does have a hard limit](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) of 32,767 characters per cell.

Comment: Yeah even I didn't find anywhere in the php documentation  about character limit and so thought to ask if there is any limit set like Microsoft excel. In my code there is a process which copies some content that has more than 32000 characters  and then writes into excel and creates spreadsheet. And I noticed that contents was getting stripped out, and only showed approx 32000 characters for php excel too. But thanks for your response though.

Comment: Got it. Sounds like you ran into the document limit. Please accept if this answered your question.